# unable to login to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Today I changed my windows to windows10 x64, but surprisingly when I open gitlab (I mean gitlab.com) and try to login to my account, I face

```
422
The change you requested was rejected.

Make sure you have access to the thing you tried to change.

Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake.
```

I just want to login, that's all! The issue is not related to my account because I have tried lots of accounts. What is it about? (I am using proxy, but the proxy shouldn't be the cause, because it is a long time I am using it and I tried different proxies. Moreover I logged in git lab on windows app using the exact proxy and cloned my project easily.)

Comment: Are you using 2FA? Is it a NTP issue as in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52133#note_109168735? (Considering 2FA relies on synced clocked, as documented in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2904)

Comment: I've view this error lot of times when you have the login window opened for lot of time (for example, all the night you have an explorer tab on gitlab login page). If you retry to login, normally it does correctly (if you don't have 2FA enabled, obviously). If not, try to restart the navigator.

Comment: `apt install ntp` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

One scenario which would explain that error message:

- GitLab offers [2FA (Two-Factor Authentication )](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html), where you’ll be prompted for a code generated by your one time password authenticator.
- that depends on [NTP (Network Time Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), as [documented here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2904).
- [GitLab issue 52133](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52133#note_109168735) illustrates an NTP wrong configuration can ben the cause of a 422 error message.

So double-check your [NTP settings on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/954477/141).

---

Note that with [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#duo-supported-as-a-2fa-method) (March 2023) (self-hosted only)

> ### Duo supported as a 2FA method
>
> Duo time-based one-time password (TOTP) is now supported as a two-factor authentication (2FA) method when signing into GitLab.
>
> [image: Duo integration]
>
> Thank you [Jamie Murphy](https://gitlab.com/ITJamie) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html#enable-one-time-password-using-duo) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15760).
> And [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fk0NDsx261E).